# Why does my MSBuild custom task not work?

Tags: .net, msbuild

following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/task-writing?view=vs-2019) tutorial I am trying to run a custom task during the build process. I have the following task:

```
namespace MyTasks
    {
        public class HelloWorld : Task
        {
            public override bool Execute()
            {   
                Log.LogMessage(Microsoft.Build.Framework.MessageImportance.High, "Hello World.");
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

And I've included this in another project in the following way, including another message:

```
  <UsingTask AssemblyFile="C:\Path\To\MyTasks.dll" TaskName="MyTasks.HelloWorld"/>
  <Target Name="MyTarget">
    <Message Text="I want to run a custom task." Importance="High"/>
    <HelloWorld/>
  </Target>
```

But when I build this project I don't see any of these two messages in the build output. I have tried both `<HelloWorld/>` and `<MyTasks.HelloWorld/>` and also setting the task name attribute to just `HelloWorld`.
In Visual Studio I have set both

```
Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> MSBuild project build output verbosity
```

and

```
Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> MSBuild project build log file verbosity
```

to `Normal`.

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I forgot the `BeforeTargets` attribute on the `Target` element. This is the updated target element:

```
  <Target Name="MyTarget" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Message Text="I want to run a custom task." Importance="High"/>
    <HelloWorld/>
  </Target>
```